# My Qt-Qml App crashes on symbian belle (Nokia 700)

Tags: qt, qml, symbian3

I developed an app targeting symbian ^1, symbian ^3 ( including belle) and meego
my app utilizes multimedia and it works fine for all devices except of nokia 700 (belle).
It runs well but after several open and exit, it stops running with:

> Thread has crashed: A data abort exception has occurred accessing 0x0.
>   Process has finished.

And it is no more runnable until I restart the phone.
What could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: There could be a bug in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Store the debug, error, warning messages in a text file and examine it after the crash. It may give you useful information about the crash.
If all other OSs could run it successfully without any problem, it may be an error/defect related to that OS implementation.

Comment: Yes I did this and the error is:
"A data abort exception has occurred accessing 0x0.
>*stopped,reason="signal-received",signal-name="SIGSEGV",signal-meaning="Segmentation fault",frame={addr="0x80566b38",func="??",args=[]},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all"

Comment: Usually SIGSEGV means that your code is trying to do a memory access violation [Wikipedia Example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Segmentation_fault_example). If it works in all OSs then it may be fault on the OS side. But you can still use some tools like Nokia Analyze or Valgrind to check for problems in your code. Debugging Examples for [SEGMENTATION FAULT](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html)

Comment: Thanks Raja but how to use valgrind for symbian?

Comment: You can choose it to run on the simulator while checking it with Valgrind. But since you say that your application performs well on other devices, there seems to be very little opportunity to find memory access violations during this.... Doesn't debug information shows any clue of **the line** which causes the error?.. Have you chose to log all the messages like _qWarnings_, _qCritical_, _qDebug_ etc?.. Example for logging in a file [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/File_based_logging_in_Qt_for_debugging)...